# Sorting of widgets by Rank

Tags: javascript, sorting, rank, tabular

I am trying to create a rank of widgets that sort in the order of their rank. 
I am also trying to create a corresponding table that contain descriptions of each widget that sort by rank along with the widgets.

For example, these are the widgets that would be sorted. I would like to have them display on a webpage by the 'data-rank' returned from the API along with a corresponding description that moves with the widget:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js">
<div data-currency="bitcoin" class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-
base="USD" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="true" data-
marketcap="true" data-volume="true" data-stats="USD" data-
statsticker="false"></div>
<div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="bitcoin-gold" 
data-base="USD" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="true" 
data-marketcap="true" data-volume="true" data-stats="USD" data-
statsticker="false"></div>
<div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="zcash" data-
base="USD" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="true" data-
marketcap="true" data-volume="true" data-stats="USD" data-
statsticker="false"></div>
<div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="ethereum" data-
base="USD" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="true" data-
marketcap="true" data-volume="true" data-stats="USD" data-
statsticker="false"></div></script>
```

Please help me find the best way to go about doing this, I would highly appreciate it. I am a novice developer.

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code?

Comment: That is it above. I think? Sorry, If that is not it, then I do not have any. Im using a wordpress website.

Comment: Seems to be here `https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js`